# add object value to an existing dotted key of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How to add object value to an array, while key is know and there is another value on that key, but I don't want to remove it. Also key is dotted

Here is an example

```
array = [key1:{value1},key2:{value3}];
key = this.props.name;
```

I want to get:

```
array = [key1:{value1},{value2},key2:{value3}];
```

Maybe it is better to change base object type to object or value to array?

Comment: The "I want to get" is invalid.  You would need to get something back like this:
`array = {key1:[value1,value2]},{key2:[value3]};`  
So to add a new item to the keys array you would be doing something like:
`array.key1.push(new value);`

Comment: Objects have keys, not arrays. You can't do an array the way you have it written

Comment: As @hajile78 has pointed out, your desired output is not a valid structure in JavaScript. You'd need to wrap those objects in an array.

Comment: `array = {key1:[value1,value2],key2:[value3]};`

Comment: @hajile78 yes, I was wrong. But still as key1 is    this.props.name, I can't use array.key1.push(new value);

Comment: Is this.props.name the key or the array your trying to add to?  If it's the key you can use `let key = this.props.name; array[key].push(new value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store values with keys it's better use object and arrays as values:

```
obj = {
   key1: [value1],
   key2: [value3]
}
```

then if you want to update the object

```
obj[this.props.name] = [...obj[this.props.name], 'newItem']
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant way to accomplish what it seems like you are trying to do.